# I am trying to create a toggle button that turns on or off a person's availability status and update the current status in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

for now this is what i have, it is toggling but the boolean value isn't changing in database

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="availability" id="toggle-one">
```

i have this script controlling the toggle

```
<script> 
  $(function() { 
      $('#toggle-one').bootstrapToggle({ 
          on: 'Available', 
          off: 'Not Available' 
      }); 
  })
```

And this is the field in schema

```
  availability:{
    type:Boolean,
    default:false
},
```

no help is too small, i just need someone to point me in the right direction, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the events and assign true or false based on its state like this

```
$(function() {
$('#toggle-on').change(function() {
   console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
//in schema that you are sending to server assign value of $(this).prop('checked')
 })
});
```